# Create mutliple branches from many commits from one large branch

Tags: git, shell, github

I have a large feature branch where I have been doing a lot of really small code cleanups (which are all related). This branch consists of some ~100+ or so commits, each around 1-5 lines each, and each usually only touches 1, maybe 2 files.

My team and I prefer to keep pull requests as small as possible, in order to make it easier to review and to revert in case something goes wrong.

My question is what is the best way to "automagically" pull (let's say) 5 commits at a time into their own new branch from my large feature branch, then push them, then repeat until there are no more commits in the feature branch?

I know how I would do this manually, and the process looks something like this:

```sh
# Go to branch we want PRs to target:
git checkout main

# New PR branch:
git checkout -b cleanup/part-1

# Grab some commits from the large cleanup branch:
git cherry-pick <SOME_COMMIT_HASH>
git cherry-pick <SOME_COMMIT_HASH>
git cherry-pick <SOME_COMMIT_HASH>
git cherry-pick <SOME_COMMIT_HASH>
git cherry-pick <SOME_COMMIT_HASH>

# Push, create a PR, then repeat steps for ~100 commits :\
git push
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, as I feel like this will be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't expect to do changes on your merge/pull requests, you could simply add the branch labels to the commits in question. `gitk` can help with that: simply click on the commit and choose "create branch"; then push this branch. Of course, this is possible to do on the command line too, but that requires a bit more typing (`git branch pr1 commithash` and you need to find out the commit hashes first).

Let me illustrate:

```
o <- your-branch
o
o <- pr3
o
o <- pr2
o
o <- pr1
o
```

"your-branch" is your original branch containing all changes. `pr1` will only contain the first two changes.

Create `pr1`, push, create PR/MR, have it reviewed and merged. Then push `pr2`, push, have it merged. Rinse and repeat. Once a branch has been merged, its changes won't show up in future PR/MRs of the follow-up branches (Git can detect through the DAG which commits are new and need to be merged vs which have already merged earlier).

That's ~20 steps for 100 commits if you always group 5 commits. Quite an improvement already.

If your task can be achieved by stubbornly taking every n-th commit, then you can use a shell loop to create the branches, e.g.:

```
git rev-list --reverse main..your-branch \
  | sed -n '0~5p' \
  | nl \
  | while read -r num commit; do \
      git branch "pr-$num" "$commit"; \
    done
```

(The sed call can be replaced with `awk 'NR % 5 == 0'`, but it should not really matter. The result will be identical on most systems)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility here is a "semi-automatic" approach: use some git commands, and a text editor of your choice, to create some more git commands, and then run them.

*Note: This answer relies on bash-specific syntax. If you're using another shell, like zsh, you'll need to adapt some things. I also make no guarantee that this is correct; I had fun writing it, but haven't actually tested it all.*

### Step 1: Create a whole lot of branches

Start off by listing out the history of the branch, but get git to pre-create some "git branch" commands for you, and pipe them to a file:

```sh
git log --reverse main..HEAD --pretty='# git branch cleanup/part-$((part++)) %h # %s' | tee branch-commands.sh
```

This will generate a commented out command for every commit, which would create a branch at that commit. The `$((part++))` is bash syntax for incrementing a counter, so that each line actually run gets the next number.

Edit the file, and uncomment the lines where you want each PR to end - the one-line commit messages are at the end after another comment marker.

Run the resulting script: now you have your initial branches.

### Step 2: rebase the branches to be independent

Right now, all of these branches would have to be merged exactly in order. If you want to just raise all the PRs at once, you'll want them all to be based on the same starting point. So let's generate some "git rebase" commands.

This reuses the $part variable from the end of the last loop to get the highest part number created. Alternatively, check `git branch | grep 'cleanup/part-'` for the list and substitute the number for "part" below.

The loop starts at 1, not 0, because the first part already starts at "main".

```sh
for ((p=1; p<part; p++)); do echo "git rebase --onto main cleanup/part-$((p-1)) cleanup/part-$p"; done | tee rebase-commands.sh
```

This should give you a rebase command for every branch, which takes the commits since the last branch, and rebases them onto "main".

If you're feeling confident, just run it directly rather than spitting out the commands:

```sh
for ((p=1; p<part; p++)); do git rebase --onto main cleanup/part-$((p-1)) cleanup/part-$p; done
```

### Step 3: Push to github

Let's use that loop again, starting at 0 this time.

```sh
for ((p=0; p<part; p++)); do git push origin cleanup/part-$p; done
```

### Step 4: Create the PRs

You could automate this bit using the Github API, but that's a bit more effort. We can generate all the "create PR" URLs though:

```sh
for ((p=0; p<part; p++)); do echo "https://github.com/REPO-ACCOUNT/REPO-NAME/compare/main...cleanup/part-$p?expand=1"; done | tee pr-urls.txt
```

Or even build some HTML:

```sh
for ((p=0; p<part; p++)); do echo "<a href='https://github.com/REPO-ACCOUNT/REPO-NAME/compare/main...cleanup/part-$p?expand=1'>Part $p</a><br>"; done | tee pr-urls.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Vim you change the phrases pick to reword for the commits you want to alternate [guide](https://www.boneheadphone.com/can-headphones-dent-your-head/), keep and end(:wq). Then git will set off you with each devote which you marked as reword so that you can exchange the devote message.